# Passing data to detailVC in MVP architecture

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers. I want to pass data from mainVC to detailVC during preparing segue. What's better option: calling and pass data to secondVCpresenter (which update View) or directly pass data to secondVC?

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {

var dataToSend = [Data]
.
.
.

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? DetailVC {
            destVC.detailPresenter.setData(data: dataToSend)
        }

class DetailVC: UIViewController {

 lazy var detailPresenter = DetailPresenter(detailDelegate: self)
    
    var newData = [Data] 

extension DetailVC: DetailDelegate {
    func setData(data: [Data]) {
        newData = data
    }
}

protocol DetailDelegate: class {
    
    func setData(data: [Data])
}

class DetailPresenter {
    
    weak var detailDelegate DetailDelegate?

    init(detailDelegate: DetailDelegate) {
        self.detailDelegate = detailDelegate
    }
    
    func setData(data: [Data]) {
        detailDelegate?.setData(data: data)
    }
}
```

I wonder if it is ok to call detailPresenter from prepare segue in MainVC and if it is not too dirty way to send data?

Comment: I think instead of perform segue you should use instantiating VC and then passing data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Kudos, in this case there's no need for a delegate to pass data to `DetailVC` as it's already referenced. Using a delegate for this has made it unnecessarily complicated. So yes calling `detailPresenter` is quite a dirty way of doing things.

Comment: If passing data using delegate is dirty way, so better way is pass data directly from MainVC to DetailVC?

Comment: Yes, passing directly would reduce your dependency on a delegate. That means you don't need a delegate at all in this case so your code is cleaner and more maintainable.